# UART and RS422 Interfacing

Tags: stm32, serial, rs422

Do I have to connect the Logic side of an RS422 transceiver to a UART on my STM32, or can I connect the logic side to any GPIO on the STM32?

Comment: While you could send GPIO levels over a RS422 link of you wanted to, it's far more common to use it for UART comms.

Comment: It depends on what is being transferrred over RS-422. Do you know what you are receiving or transmitting? Some rotary position encoders and e.g. AES/EBU audio links do use RS-422 but are definitely not UART.

Answer (score 2):

RS-422 can be used to send any kind of digital signal. That said, its primary use is for serial data so would want to connect to a UART port.

I presume that the UART pin could also be programmed to GPIO if desired.

Comment: Indeed, primary use is serial data, but there are many serial data interfaces, not just UART.

Answer (score 0):

> or can I connect the logic side to any GPIO on the STM32?

You can, but for the purpose of sending/receiving data with so-called "bit banging", GPIO will be a pain in the neck to use and you really ought to be using an UART peripheral instead.

However, there are legitimate reasons to connect the incoming data to an input capture timer bin, if you for example want to implement automatic baudrate detection.

Comment: Depending on STM32, it might already have an UART capable of automatic baudrate detection. If this is even for UART. Maybe it is for receiving AES3 or SSI, so neither UART or GPIO will work.

Comment: @Justme The question is clearly about UART since it says so. I was making an example of when it might be justified to route a UART signal to GPIO.